# How search for ".cricket" in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, search

I get a lot of spam from the ".cricket" domain. I want to look more closely at these messages, so I want to find all the messages with an address containing ".cricket".  If I search for ".cricket", Outlook ignores the period and shows me everything with "cricket" in it. This applies both with and without quotes around the search term.

How can I tell Outlook that when I say I want to see only messages containing the exact sequence of characters ".cricket", that's what I mean?

Because Outlook and I often have difficulty coming to agreement on what I want it to search for, I'm interested in the general answer to the question. I know I can narrow Outlook's search to headers only, but that's independent of the general searching problem.

Comment: I understand that Outlook's search feature uses an index which does not store punctuation, symbols and "noise" words like conjunctions. I think you might want to look at using a Message Rule instead.

Comment: specifically, see the "with specific words in the sender's address" rule: http://www.outlook-tips.net/how-to/creating-rules-that-apply-to-an-entire-domain/

Comment: @Dai: I'd prefer not to use a message rule, because (1) it'd be a throwaway rule, so I'd have to get rid of it after using it, and (2) I'd presumably have to set up a temporary folder to store the results in, and then I'd have to move them back to their original folder(s) and get rid of the temporary folder.